# Is $n = 0$ in proofs involving mathematical induction a rigorous expression?

Tags: induction, terminology

I have had this confusion from high school. In proofs involving mathematical induction, we always say for $n = 0$, blablabla, so that a certain condition holds for $n = 0$. After I learned logic, I found "$n = 0$" may not be a rigorous way of expression. It is in fact a replacement of $n$ by $0$ in $Q\left(n\right)$, where $Q$ is an arbitrary predicate, and we want to prove $\left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\right)Q\left(n\right)$. Replacement does not indicate any equality at all. And assume that you would like to finish the proof by asserting $Q\left(n+1\right)$ from $Q\left(n\right)$, then everyone would agree that "for $n = n+1$" is a ridiculous expression. I am wondering why people are still insisting on using the type of expression "$n = 0$" in proofs without explanation in a book at an introductory level. Especially in classes, wouldn't it cause confusions to students who do not understand logic?

Comment: Do you know anyone who was ever confused by this phrase?

Comment: @saulspatz Actually, I was when I was in high school. I didn't understand predicates and replacement, and I was wondering if I had to introduce equality to argue the case $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"n=0" is a perfectly clear statement.

If using the Peano axioms for the natural numbers you found them on $0$ (some versions start at $1$) then $0$ is defined to be the unique natural number which is not a successor. Given that $n$ is a natural number, you then have a test for whether it is equal to zero or not.

The induction step is that $Q(Sn)$ (which is informally $Q(n+1)$) follows from $Q(n)$ and the Peano axioms imply that if $Q(0)$ is also true then $Q(n)$ is true for all natural numbers.

Now if you want to go back to the foundational arguments of Set Theory, successorship and induction are further abstracted and have to be realised in a different context and a rather different language.

But I learned induction as an "obvious" property of natural numbers before I was introduced to Peano.

I think that Peano, set theory and informal introduction are three different levels of abstraction/precision. As tools, mathematicians use them as necessary, choosing which is appropriate to their context. Later we prove that they are consistent with each other and that the arguments are valid whatever level they are expressed at (though some mathematicians and systems exclude induction, or forms of induction).

I think your issue probably results from mixing the levels of abstraction/precision. Statements like $n=n+1$ do sometimes get used. They are best avoided, because they are formally false and can be confusing. But in context they often represent clunky abbreviations for true statements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find anything wrong with the expression $n=0$.

Let's say you want to prove that for all nonnegative integer $n$, the statement $Q(n)$ is true.

In the base step you first show that when $n=0$, $Q(n)$ is true, i.e., $Q(0)$ is true.

In the induction step, you then show that if $Q(n)$ is true, then $Q(n+1)$ is also true.

---

"for $n=n+1$" is nonsense does not imply that "$n=0$" is evil.

Comment: The thing is, is there any equality indicated here? I totally understand everyone who's worked in math for several years does not have this issue. But I highly doubt what would happen if you ask a high school or college student what's the meaning of $n = 0$ here. Can he/she differentiate between equality and replacement in a a predicate? At least as I observed, teachers do not teach concepts of predicates, and this type of writing appears naturally in everyday classes.

Comment: @ZiqiFan: I don't think the notion of "predicates" is relevant unless one wants to discuss logic *per se* or studies in detail what mathematical induction *is* or studies what second-order Peano Arithmetic means. As far as *applying* the mathematical induction goes, I don't find it difficult (for students) to understand what it means by says "show the statement is true when $n=0$".

Comment: Where do we need an equality here? Sometimes you don't have equalities but inequalities. If you mean $n=0$, that's a perfect expression, for the inductive case you could use $n=h$ hence you have to prove the statement for $n=h+1$, but it is convention.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand. We have started using things like $x = 3$ for evaluating a function at a very early age, even from primary school...But is it really good to teach without explanation for the symbol "="?